# How can I add a custom button to the titlebar on a single page of a navigation.View (Sencha Touch 2)?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm using a navigation.View to hold a list, so I can easily implement a detail view which appears when someone clicks on an item. I also have a search bar docked at the top of this list view, but what I'd like to do is hide this by default and have a button within the titlebar which would allow the user to show/hide the search bar.

I've tried using the following code to achieve this:

```
navigationBar: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        align: 'right',
        text: 'Search'
    }]
}
```

but this causes the button to display on every page I push into the navigation view, whereas I want the button to only appear on the root list page. Is this even possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you had better not use `Ext.NavigationView`. Just use normal views which toolbars.

But if you still want to use navigation view, here maybe a hint to start with:

1. Add that button to your navigation bar and set config `hidden: true` by default.
2. Listen for an event which can observe when your active view is changed. This may vary depending on your app structure.
3. When your "special" view is activated, show that button to the navigation bar, and when it is deactivated, hide that button.

Comment: Thanks Thiem, I had come to that solution just after posting the question... I gave the button item an id, added it to the controller and hid it on itemTap and showed it on the back event of the navigationview. It was a workable solution, but the animation would have to be added manually in order to fit in with the page transitions etc... in the end I decided to go with a different layout altogether.

I appreciate the advice, thanks again.

Comment: In there any other way if consider I have two different navigation views and I need to show one common view in both of them, IN that case how can I add a button to the navigation view.